# uint8_t iostream behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

I was expecting the code: `cout << uint8_t(0);` to print `0`, but it doesn't print anything.

When I try to stream `uint8_t` objects to `cout`, I get strange characters with gcc. Is this expected behavior? Could it be that `uint8_t` is an alias for some `char`-based type? See compiler/system notes below.

```c++
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

void print(const uint8_t& n)
{
    std::cout << ">>>" << n                 << "<<<    "
              << ">>>" << (unsigned int)(n) << "<<<\n";
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b(0);
    uint8_t c = 0;
    uint8_t d{0};
    uint8_t e = 1;
    uint8_t f = 2;

    // Note that the first print statement uses an unset uint8_t
    // and therefore the behaviour is undefined. (Included here for
    // completeness)
    for (auto i : {a, b, c, d, e, f})
    {
        print(i);
    }
}
```

Compiling and running it as follows:

```bash
g++ test-uint8.cpp -std=c++11 && ./a.out
```

- using `gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)`
- on the system `Linux 3.7.9-101.fc17.x86_64`

... produces the output:

```
>>>�<<<   >>>194<<<
>>><<<    >>>0<<<
>>><<<    >>>0<<<
>>><<<    >>>0<<<
>>><<<    >>>1<<<
>>><<<    >>>2<<<
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uint8\_t can't be printed with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cout uint8\_t as integers instead of chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246154/cout-uint8-t-as-integers-instead-of-chars)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char`, and the iostreams have special overloads for chars that print out the characters rather than formatting numbers.

The conversion to integer inhibits this.

Answer (score 7):

> Could it be that uint8_t is an alias for some char-based type?

Absolutely. It's required to be a typedef for a builtin 8-bit unsigned integral type, if such a type exists. Since there are only two possible 8-bit unsigned integral types, `char` for a compiler that treats it as unsigned and `unsigned char`, it must be one of those. Except on systems where `char` is larger than 8 bits, in which case it won't exist.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that uint8_t may not exist! Didn't know that.

Comment: @Johann - for most uses, `uint_least8_t` is a better choice than `uint8_t`.

Comment: An implementation is allowed to provide more extended integer types which are not aliases for the standard integer types.  So I think technically `uint8_t` *could* be a non-character type, although it's usually not.

Comment: @PeteBecker `uint_least8_t` didn't work, it's the same as `uint8_t `.

Comment: Yes, the C++ compiler treats it as `char`, where C compiler treats it as `unsigned char` which would output a numerical value.

Comment: @R1S8K `uint_least8_t` wouldn't work because it's almost certainly still `unsigned char`. The difference is that the `least` types are required to be there, while the *exact* size types are not. `uint_least8_t` is a better choice because it's guaranteed to exist, but not because it will work differently, though it may if it's not 8 bits. I assume you already figured this out given how old this comment is, but I figured this might help future readers :)

Comment: @WillEccles I appreciate the comment anytime. But anyway the details along these types aren't clear to me right now because I'm mostly working in C for embedded programming. `uint8_t` is my most type of data for 8-bits. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @R1S8K I do embedded as well and can't really imagine a system where at least uint8_t (or a similar type) is not defined. In practice, I have never personally used a system where these types were not defined. Just thought I'd clarify for future readers :)

Comment: @WillEccles — not my area, but I’ve heard that there are DSP chips where the smallest addressable storage is 16 (or even 32) bits, so no `uint8_t`.

Comment: @WillEccles Yes they all are defined in `stdint.h` or `inttypes.h` and haven't thought of using `uint_least8_t`, does it have advantages over `uint8_t` ?

Comment: @R1S8K Not really, aside from the fact that it's actually required to exist. Most implementations will define the optional `uint8_t` anyway, if possible. C does not require that an implementation have a type that is exactly 8 bits, since it's possible that one might not. If you have `uint8_t`, you should use it. I see no reason why not.

Comment: @WillEccles Yes, going back to the reason of this thread because my comment was long ago and based on my simple experience in C, the answers were of course deep enough for the thread question, but I think I wrote my comment thinking maybe I contributed to the thread, but I think I didn't pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `uint8_t` is streamed as an `unsigned char`. I've sometimes made use of bit fields from integer types that *are* streamed as, well, integers, to avoid having to cast or overload `operator<<`, but only when it doesn't waste space, like in the Pos struct below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct WasteAbyte {
    unsigned short has_byte_range:8;
};

struct Pos {
    unsigned short x:8;
    unsigned short y:8;
};

int main() {
    WasteAbyte W = {255};

    ++W.has_byte_range;

    std::cout << W.has_byte_range << std::endl;

    std::cout << sizeof(WasteAbyte) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(Pos) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
2
2
```

Comment: Why does using bit fields make the streamed values get interpreted as such instead of characters? Is this portable behaviour?

Comment: @IanGralinski Because the underlaying type is an `unsigned short` for which  numeric values is printed. Yes it's portable.