# cout uint8_t as integers instead of chars

Tags: c++, stream

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << (uint8_t)123 << endl;
}
```

This will output `{` , since `{`'s ASCII is 123.

But I want to get `123` instead. I found `cout << (int)123 << endl;` will do this, but I'm not willing to cast `uint_8` to `int` every times. Can I configure `cout` to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you pass an actual int, what do you mean by every time your code runs once

Comment: @aaronman I got an function which returns a array of `uint_8`, I don't want to use cast when I try to write that array to cout...

Comment: if it's important to the question you should post it with the rest, as of now the question really makes no sense

Comment: Make a helper function to do it.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question. Even if someone thinks it's unclear, it can be clearly edited to be made clear. And there's close vote there again. The close vote system is really broken, and random people just go around and suggest to close anything that they "feel" not comfortable with.

Comment: What's wrong with the cast?

Comment: @WiSaGaN I'm perfectly willing to retract my close vote if he improves the question, right now his whole code is 1 line that really means nothing to me

Comment: Could you clarify the "or something else"?  Because that's quite vague, and would also include casting to `int`, had you not explicitly forbade it.  That is to say, if you're not willing to cast it, there must be other things you're also not willing to do.  So please clarify exactly what are the parameters of "or something else".

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Okay, I think configure `cout` is preferable.

Comment: Why not `cout << 123 << endl;`?

Comment: @user93353 In practice I got an array of `uint_8`...

Comment: @Sayakiss Surely you're not printing the array out by repeatedly typing `cout << myarr[0] << myarr[1] ... << myarr[n]`. Make a loop to print it, and then the explicit cast isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I definitely do not condone the solution I am about to suggest.  I also suspect that it may not be permitted by the standard, but I cannot prove it, as of yet.  If someone can provide me a reference that shows that it is not permitted, then I will delete this answer.  Anyway, my tests so far indicate that simply overloading the operator in the global scope seems to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, std::uint8_t val)
{
    return os << static_cast<int>(val);
}

int main()
{
    std::uint8_t val = 123;
    std::cout << val;
}
```

I wouldn't have thought this would work, but then I realized that the `char/unsigned char/signed char` overloads for `operator<<` are all free functions in the `std` namespace picked up by ADL.  And I guess global functions are considered a better match than ADL functions, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: well it's more clever than my solution

Comment: I think the reason your version is chosen over the `operator<<` overloads for `((un)signed) char` is because the [latter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) are function templates and the version you have is more specialized. If you make yours a template also, the [default one gets chosen](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c61d5d5eb16066c4c2197a22de9a7a8c-6e9f1f680880347f6708b805c806db62); but my example is surely an ODR violation. Anyway, I don't think you're allowed to provide `operator<<` for fundamental types.

Comment: @Praetorian: Yep, that makes sense. But why do you think it's not allowed?  Just a gut feeling?

Comment: Yep, that's all it is. I have no clue where to even begin looking in the standard for something to corroborate that.