# I get ASCII symbols from BMP header instead numbers

Tags: c++, bmp

I'm trying to get BITMAPFILEHEADER part from .bmp file. I expected to see some numbers, but have ASCII symbols. How to solve this problem?

```
std::string path;
std::ifstream file;

path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Emp.bmp";

file.open(path);

if (!file.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "ERROR";
}
else
{
    char fromfile[14];

    file.read(fromfile, 14);

    std::cout << fromfile;
    file.close();
}
```

I tried to translate ASCII output to HEX-symbols and I have correct data (It matches with HEX-editor data), but I can't understand why I get ASCII from program output

Comment: `char fromfile[14]` array of `char`. `file.read(fromfile, 14);` Read into array of `char`.  `std::cout << fromfile;` print array of `char`.  Because most of the time when you want to print an array of `char`, you want to display a null terminated string, this will print the data read as if it was a string and probably print too little or too much depending on the placement of the first null found and the age of the compiler (modern C++ standards will detect the length of the array and stop. Older compilers will take the array as a pointer and overflow if they don't find a null character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cout uint8\_t as integers instead of chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246154/cout-uint8-t-as-integers-instead-of-chars)

Comment: In C++, for your own sake, use `std::vector` and avoid C style arrays. These can be sized at will to whatever length you want.

Comment: I recommend using `uint8_t` instead of `char` because `char` can be signed or unsigned or `char`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
std::cout << fromfile;
```

Treats `fromfile` as if it was a null-terminated string, because it is an array of `char`s.

If you want to see the numeric value of the bytes, you can use:

```
for (auto const & c : fromfile)
{
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << ", ";
}
```

If you want to see only positive values (since `char` can be signed), the loop body should be:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) << ", ";
```

And if you want hex values replace it with:

```
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) << ", ";
```

Another issue is that you open the file in text mode (the default), instead of opening it in binary mode which is more suited for your purpose:

```
//--------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-
file.open(path, std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: A note on why you want binary mode: Opening a file in text mode allows the program to convert the data read from the file to make it easier to manipulate and display as text.  The most common result is seeing the carriage return linefeed combination replaced with a newline character or vice-versa on write. Somewhere in the file you could (and often do have at least one) binary pattern that by dumb luck matches, is substituted, and your parser gets the wrong character or the wrong data is written to the file. This can be an absolute <expletive deleted> to debug.