# std::copy raw data to cout in hex format using ostream_iterator<uint8_t> prints out unformatted data. Why?

Tags: c++, iterator, iostream

The idea is to have a vector containing arbitrary binary data and outputting the bytes it contains to stdout in hexadecimal notation. I use std::copy to copy the bytes from the input vector to stdout. The problem is that the code prints out 0 followed by raw binary data. Here is the code:

```
auto vec = std::vector<uint8_t> {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2);
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<uint8_t>(std::cout));
```

The application prints out "0hello". I would expect it to print out "68656C6C6F". What can be the case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple change, use `int` instead of `uint8_t`:

```
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
```

If you want it in uppercase, use [`std::uppercase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/uppercase).

`operator<<` has [non-member overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`. See: [uint8_t iostream behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296661/uint8-t-iostream-behavior).

Comment: Thank you, that explains it!

Comment: @alvarez: It's because of the non-member overloads mentioned above.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Can anyone suggest something else, or why it may not be working? I'm using an ostringstream instead of cout.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `std::cout` in

```
std::ostream_iterator<uint8_t>(std::cout)
```

with `std::cout<<std::hex` and `uint8_t` with `int`

```
std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout<<std::hex)
```

This works because `<<` operator returns reference to the modified stream, which is passed further to the iterator. Also you can combine it with other modificators such as [std::showbase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase), e.g.

```
std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout<<std::showbase<<std::hex, " ")
```