# Why is reading uint8_t as hex not working as expected?

Tags: c++, iostream

Consider code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "a0 b1";

    uint8_t byte;
    ss >> std::hex >> byte;    

    std::cout << std::hex << byte << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this output `a` instead of `a0` even though `a0` fits in `uint8_t` as hex?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `uint8_t` is also (probably) `unsigned char`, for which [special rules exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15296695/560648) when you perform *formatted extraction* from a C++ stream.

Unfortunately [this is just an alias, not a distinct type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146349/560648).

Basically it's skipping the "lexically convert to a number" step because it thinks you want to pull out a character. The character `'a'`.

I think you'll want to read into an `unsigned int` then downsize if needed.

If you do downsize to a `uint8_t`, you're also going then to have to promote it back to a larger int (lol) for [much the same reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562163/560648), to trigger serialisation.

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24a07b0680652c8e))

To be honest I'd just avoid the small fixed-width types when dealing with streams (unless you're doing unformatted work with `read()` and `write()`). It's too easy to forget about this problem.

Comment: Yeah, the code looks really stupid with all those casts :)

Comment: @Brandon The unary plus operator causes the `uint8_t` operand be promoted to `int`, which becomes type of the expression result.

Comment: @Brandon That's [the cheat's way to perform the mentioned integral promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903114/560648).

Comment: If I am not mistaken the base type of c++ streams is char not an unsigned char. How would this influence the result?

Comment: @Bart The base type is irrelevant. IOStreams have special overloads for `char`ry things. Otherwise streaming your `'a'` `'b'` `'c'` etc would not work properly. (Actually it's more like it has special overloads for **non** `char`ry things; that's your `int`, `bool` etc. But you get so used to it that you forget `char`, `unsigned char` etc _don't_ do that.)