# c++ stringstream read doesn't seem to read the whole buffer

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have the following code: https://godbolt.org/z/9aqqe5eYh

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
  std::string line = "fa0834dd";

  for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i += 2) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::uint8_t byte;

    ss << std::hex << line.substr(i, 2);
    std::cout << ss.str() << " ";
    ss >> byte;
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << byte << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Ideally, this takes in a string of hex numbers, splits them into bytes (pair of hex digits) and stores it into bytes (for illustrative purposes, I use only one `std::uint8_t` above).
The above code outputs this:

```
Program returned: 0
Program stdout
fa  f
08  0
34  3
dd  d
```

Which seems kinda odd. An `std::uint8_t` should be enough to store 2 hex character's worth of data. But it seems like `ss >> byte` only stores the front hex character. My guess is that:

```cpp
ss << std::hex << line.substr(i, 2);
```

actually stores each hex character as 1 byte?

How would I fix the above code to generate an single-byte value equal to 2 hex characters in the string?

Comment: You need to parse the string and translate it into a (hex) number instead of put string directly into a byte. Because most of platform one char is one byte.

Comment: Eg: using [strol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606613/4123703)

Comment: See also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296661/uint8-t-iostream-behavior) which is related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringstream` is not eligible for parsing the character representation into a value in byte.

You may use something lik `strtol` to actually parse the string into value.

```
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
  std::string line = "fa0834dd";

  for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i += 2) {
    std::string ss = line.substr(i,2);
    
    std::cout << ss << " ";

    std::uint8_t byte = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(strtol(ss.c_str(), NULL, 16));
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast(byte) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

[Ref post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606613/4123703)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `std::hex` only applies to integer input/output, and while `uint8_t` is technically an integer, it just an `unsigned char` underneath, and  `iostream` will input and output its character value rather than its integer value. In other words, your loop puts two characters into the `stringstream`, and then extracts the first character back out again.

If you want to convert hex data to native integer types, you can use [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or a similar function. For example (extracting the first byte only):

```
std::string hexdata = "01020304";
size_t length;

// attempt to convert just the first two characters
uint8_t firstbyte = std::stoi(hexdata.substr(0, 2), &length, 16);

// "length" is set to the number of characters successfully parsed
// so if it is not the same number of characters that you supplied,
// then there's an issue. In this case, we are expected 2.
if (length != 2)
{
    std::cerr << "was that hex??" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    // you'll need to cast it to an integer type in order to see its integer value
    // otherwise iostreams will just output the character value
    std::cout << "value of byte is " << static_cast<int>(firstbyte) << std::end;
}
```

`std::stoi` may also throw an exception if there was absolutely no conversion possible at all (e.g. none of the characters in the supplied string were convertible).

Comment: Thanks, I realized that trying to print a single byte is also not possible with cout (I ran into this before but forgot :S).